# Find max value of a dataframe column containing numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I was trying to find the maximum value of a column in a dataframe that contains numpy arrays.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 33, 4],
                   'a': [1, 22, 23, 44],
                   'b': [1, 42, 23, 42]})
df['new'] = df.apply(lambda r: tuple(r), axis=1).apply(np.array)
```

This how the dataframe can look like:

```
    id  a   b   new
0   1   1   1   [1, 1, 1]
1   2   22  42  [2, 22, 42]
2   33  23  23  [33, 23, 23]
3   4   44  42  [4, 44, 42]
```

Now I want to find the maximum (single) value of column new. In this case it is 44. What about a quick and easy way?

Comment: `df["new"].apply(max).max()` ?

Comment: Do the arrays in new always have the same dimension?

Comment: Yes, alway the same dimension! In the real world it has up to 8000 entries.

Answer (score 1):

Because your `new` column is actually constructed from the columns `id`, `a`, `b`. Before you create the `new` column you can do:

```
single_max = np.max(df.values)
```

OR if you insist on your dataframe to contain the `new` column and then get max you can do:

```
single_max = np.max(df.drop('new',axis=1).values)
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
df.new.explode().max()
```

---

Or a faster alternative:

```
np.max(np.vstack(df.new.values))
```

---

Returns `44`.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a lambda to the values that calls the array's `max` method. This would result in a Series that also has a `max` method.

```
df['new'].apply(lambda arr: arr.max()).max()
```

Just guessing, but this should be faster than `.apply(max)` because you use the optimized array method instead of converting the numpy ints to python ints one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want to consider the columns "new":

```
import numpy as np
out = np.max(tuple(df['new'])) # or np.max(df['new'].tolist())
```

Output: `44`

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.new.map(pd.eval).explode().max()
```

Output: 44

Answer (score 0):

**1-** Combination  of `max` and `explode()`

```py
df['new'].explode().max()
# 44
```

**2-** List comprehension

```py
max([max(e) for e in df['new']])
# 44
```